# Python3 help determining most pythonic approach to dynamically creating a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Looking for assistance from the experts here to help make good choices in a program that I am creating.  Which of the two approaches for creating a list appears more Pythonic and readable to you?  Or is there a better way that I could be doing this?

## Approach #1 - list comprehension

```
def test_func(*args):
    s = 'Country name: United {nm}'
    l = [s.format(nm='States') if x is 'us' 
         else s.format(nm='Arab Emirates') if x is 'uae'
         else s.format(nm='Kingdom') if x is 'uk' 
         else 'Unknown' for x in args]
    return l

# execute
test_func('us', 'uk', 'uae')

# results
['Country name: United States',
 'Country name: United Kingdom',
 'Country name: United Arab Emirates']
```

## Approach #2 - for loop

```
def test_func(*args):
    s = 'Country name: United {nm}'
    l = []
    for arg in args:
        if arg is 'us':
            l.append(s.format(nm='States'))
        elif arg is 'uk':
            l.append(s.format(nm='Kingdom'))
        elif arg is 'uae':
            l.append(s.format(nm='Arab Emirates'))
        else:
            l.append(s.format(nm='Unknown'))
    return l

# execute
test_func('us', 'uk', 'uae')

# results
['Country name: United States',
 'Country name: United Kingdom',
 'Country name: United Arab Emirates']
```

Comment: Aside: don't use `is` for string comparisons.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) on the difference between `is` and `==`.

Comment: The more pythonic approach would be to use a `dict` mapping here, like the answer below, but in general, nested conditional expressions are not very readable IMO. For-loops are pretty much always pythonic.

Comment: #2 - `United Unknown`? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mapping at the wrong level.  Use a dict like:

#### Code:

```
def test_func(*args):
    mapping = {
        'us': 'United States',
        'uae': 'United Arab Emirates',
        'uk': 'United Kingdom',
    }
    return ['Country name: {}'.format(mapping.get(x, 'Unknown')) for x in args]

# execute
print(test_func('us', 'uk', 'uae', 'xyzzy'))
```

#### Results:

```
[
    'Country name: United States', 
    'Country name: United Kingdom', 
    'Country name: United Arab Emirates',
    'Country name: Unknown'
]
```

Comment: Maybe  use `.get` to handle OP's "Unknown" case?